# What are the parts of speech in the sentence: Regular exercise strengthens the heart, thereby reducing the risk of heart attack

Tags: conjunctions, parts-of-speech

Can anyone break this sentences into parts of speech?

> Regular exercise strengthens the heart, thereby reducing the risk of heart attack

What is the conjunction in this sentence joining the two clauses of the sentence?

Why is the word coming after *thereby* written in “*-ing* form”?  I do not understand this grammar with -ing.

Comment: There is no conjunction in the sentence, and there is only one clause, with a participle phrase (‘reducing’ is a participle), denoting consequence.  You could make it into two clauses by replacing “thereby reducing” with “and so reduces”.  It means the same thing.

Comment: Dear tuffy thank you so much for ur help, but i have a huge confusion in this sentence.  Ist : can you break each word of the sentence in parts of speech so that it can be more clear to me. 2nd is it possible that a non -ing ending word can come after thereby in other scenerio

Comment: I can do the second thing at least.  The answer is no you cannot:  not without replacing 'thereby' with 'and so, exactly as I have done.  "..., thereby (after a comma) commits the writer to using a participle.  If you use the original version with a participle, then you can say that the participle, "reducing" agrees with the subject of the main verb.  So it is the 'regular exercise' which is doing the reducing.  If it is a gerund you want, then you could say "regular exercise reduces the risk of heart attack by strengthening the heart.  I do not know whether this will help you at all.

Comment: Dear Tuffy i really appreciate the pain you have taken to explain the answer to me.  Through your efforts the picture is somewhat clear to me but not to its fullest as i am a not a native og english. But i have started to learn the sentences by breaking them into parts of speech. This way gives me much better picture of every doubt. Yes i agree that breaking every sentence into parts of speech is a tough job but still i am trying.  Once i get the answer which my mind is looking for i will definitely share with you.  And once again thanks frm bottom of my heart to share your knowledge with me